# What underlayment should I use for stapled engineered floor?

Tags: engineered-flooring

What underlayment should I use for 3/8" engineered flooring stapled to plywood subfloor?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For nail down, no underlay is needed.  But for install and to help reduce noise from the wood floor rubbing against the subfloor (when someone walks on it), use red rosin paper.

Comment: Rosin paper is underlayment.